# Polar coordinates: Slope of tangent

Tags: derivatives, self-learning, polar-coordinates

[image]

Would anyone mind telling me how to solve this problem? It seems strange as my answer is $-1$.

Do I have to apply this formula, $$\frac{r'\sinθ +r\cosθ}{r'\cosθ -r\sinθ}$$ ?

Comment: this helps http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarTangents.aspx ?

Comment: I see that you just deleted you old identical question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788777/polar-coordinates-slope-of-tangent